# how to post data in API in angularJS in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, json

I am new to this field so need help.I have to post data to API but i am unable to do this.Please help me and let me now the process.

API is:     http://trendytoday.in/ers/api/DeviceAlarms

And JSOn format in which i have to send data is:

```
{
  "ers": {
    "agency_device_id": "1"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS provides the $http service, which has a method most. This can be used like:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("HttpGetController", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.SendData = function() {
    var data = {
      "ers": {
        "agency_device_id": "1"
      }
    }
    $http.post('http://trendytoday.in/ers/api/DeviceAlarms', data)
      .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      })
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="HttpGetController">
  <button ng-click="SendData()">Submit</button>
  <hr /> {{ PostDataResponse }}
</div>
```

This should be called from a controller or a service, and whichever you choose should have the $http service included as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.ers = {
      'agency_device_id' : ''

```
};

$scope.submit = function(){
          var link = 'http://trendytoday.in/ers/api/DeviceAlarms';
          $http.post(link, {ers: $scope.ers},{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }).then(function (res){
          $scope.mssg = res.data.ers.resMessage;
          $scope.resp = res.data.ers.response;
```